# How can user enter a link

Tags: jquery, mobile, input, hyperlink, textarea

In a textarea, how can a user enter a link? I am using jquery mobile.

Would the user just have to enter Text

Or should I have a button that adds the  tags when it is clicked, and will that work?

Comment: Easiest way to deal with that is the use an editor - something like TinyMCE which you can customise to only include the buttons you want. I'm not sure how compatible that is with jQuery mobile though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

best to use a wysiwig control for this.  below is a link to 10 of the best

http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/design/10-best-wysiwyg-text-and-html-editors-for-your-next-project/

YOu will need to make sure it is compatible with jquery mobile though